# Should we [glob] these two tags together?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glob) has 972 questions, and [globbing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/globbing) has 91 questions. The tag wikis don't have any information on when to use one or the other. Should they be merged together?

Comment: Both are about wildcard expansion, so it seems reasonable. Also note: [tag:wildcard-expansion] (10)